# Link My Azure DevOps Work Items in GitHub

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops

I use Azure Devops and Github togtether. I currently use Azure for managing my work items and I want to link my commits and pull request on Github to my work items on Azure DevOps.

I haven't found a suitable work around yet.

Comment: You probably already saw this, but just to cross it out, did you read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cross-service/github-integration?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

As `@Dmyto Holota` has shared, Azure DevOps has the built-in [Azure Boards-GitHub integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/github/?view=azure-devops) feature to allow users link commits and pull requests from GitHub to Azure DevOps work items.

To use this feature, you need to complete the following steps:

1. Log in the Azure DevOps project where your work items are in.
2. Go to **Project Settings** > **Boards** > **GitHub connections**.
3. Use the provided methods to set up the GitHub connections.

[image]

After above steps, you can use the Azure Boards-GitHub integration feature to link commits and pull requests from GitHub to Azure DevOps work items, and also see the status of your development from within Azure Boards.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the ways guys suggested.

Maybe you refer that you can link commit messages, and pull requests to a particular Azure DevOps work item.

Here is the way we link https://youtu.be/6sfI5MEpmXI

P.S. Use the auto-link references feature from GitHub.

Cheers,
Leo